# Nullpointerexception when using parseDouble

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, double

I've been scratching my head over this for a while.. couldn't figure out what to do.

```
String tempprice = null;
String findPriceCommand = "SELECT sellingprice FROM `item` WHERE itemNo = '" + itemNo + "'";
try 
{
    tempprice = viewValue(conn, findPriceCommand);
}
catch (SQLException e) 
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
Double price = Double.parseDouble(tempprice);
Double temp = (quantity.get(count) * price);
finalprice.add(temp);
```

All im trying to do it get the price from the database using itemNo. Since im getting this value as a string value, i used `Double price = Double.parseDouble(tempprice);` to change it to a double value.
It all worked before i turned `finalprice` into an `ArrayList` (so that i can insert multiple values at once.. (code given above is part of a loop...) Anyway, now im getting a `NullPointerException`

Like this:

```
    int count = 0;
       if (action.getSource() == btnAdd)
       {
        //other ArrayList variables 
        ArrayList<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Double> finalprice = new ArrayList<Double>();
        //.....previous code...

        count++;
       }
```

Any clue what I'm missing here? :/

Comment: tempprice is null, thats why your getting a NullPointerException

Comment: Where's the loop in the code?

Comment: You need to start using the debugger

Comment: As per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)), there is exactly one reason that you would get an NPE on `Double.parseDouble(anything)` - and that is that `anything` is `null`. So find out why. You didn't post enough info for us to find out. Your stack trace tells you exactly where the error is and there are only a small number of situations that lead to NPE's. What you missed is a basic analysis of your error and deduction of the possible causes.

Comment: @ShifaTsar, I would try setting tempprice to an empty string if that is possible. I've learned all too well and through a million and one mistakes in coding that setting a value to null will lead to a NullPointerException

Comment: I cant make `tempprice` into a double value, since im getting a string from `viewValue(conn, findPriceCommand);'.. What other option is there? Cannot compile without initializing it to something..

Comment: @ryekayo I tried that, i get a `numberformatexecption` then

Comment: @ShifaTsar The other option is to design your program properly. The only way `tempprice` is `null` is if `viewValue` returns `null` or throws an exception. In both cases, why are you proceeding to attempt to parse it despite a failure of `viewValue`? If `viewValue` is *supposed* to return `null` in certain situations, you need to handle that accordingly (e.g. `if (tempprice == null)`). Handle your error cases appropriately.

Comment: @ShifaTsar, can you try to set `tempprice = "0.0";`?

Comment: @ryekayo it worked :) Though i dont think i really understood the logic behind it much as compared to an empty string

Comment: Read the answer below. Markus pretty much summed it up

Comment: Just setting the price to "0.0" at the start is almost assuredly the WRONG approach even though it eliminates one possible reason why `tempprice` could be `null`.  First I notice you are using SQL in a way which is likely **VERY vulnerable** to mischief.  So if I give your code a bogus value for `itemNo` such that `viewValue` throws an exception, I get your product for $0.00?  Sweet deal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the API Doc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29

It says among other things that Double.parseDouble(String s) will throw a NullPointerException when s is NULL.

Just a hint. When you get any Exception take a look at the stacktrace. It will show you exactly where the exception in your case your NullPointerException arose in the first place. From there on it is only a small step to see that the problem lies somewhere in your tempprice variable. Take a debugger and step through your code to check out why tempprice is NULL.

Comment: Thanks, i shall read through tutorials on debugging.. never really bothered with that before.

Comment: @ShifaTsar: This is good introduction into debugging using Eclipse:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

If you are seriously interested in programming getting to know your debugger is a must as this will help you to develop a better model of what's going in your program. Good luck!